# Requiring JS Class inside Vuejs script tag

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I am trying to include `JS file` inside the `Vuejs script` but I cant make it work.

**JS file**

```
class Errors {
  constructor() {
    this.errors = {};
  }

  get(field) {
    if (_.has(this.errors, 'errors.' + field)) {
      return this.errors['errors'][field][0];
  }

}

module.export = {
  Errors: Errors
}
```

**Vuejs file**

```
<script>
  var { Errors } = require('../../classes');

  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        errors: new Errors
      }
    }
  }
```

**Console errors**

- `[Vue warn]: Error in data(): "TypeError: Errors is not a constructor"`
- `TypeError: Errors is not a constructor`

**Question**

How can I properly include the `JS file` inside the `Vuejs script`?
Or is it not possible?
What are my options (easy to implement options possibly)?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this out:

```
// your class file
class Error{
  //....
}
export default Error

// vue file
<script>
import Error from 'your-path'
export default {
data() {
    return {
      errors: new Error()
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe from your point of view you want to load external JS file or library like google map or maybe a Jquery script to work with Vue.

I would recommend this plugin, Vue Script2 https://github.com/taoeffect/vue-script2

It works for me to load external javascript files and is very easy to use.

Hope this will helps :)